# Force URL Parameter if none given in Laravel 4

Tags: php, routes, laravel-4, query-string

I have a web address: `http://localhost/laravel/projectx/public/user/username`

At the moment it reads the `username` to output certain results like whose page it is, which is fine, but if they type in just `http://localhost/laravel/projectx/public/user`, it redirects to `localhost/user` but I need it to render the profile user page to be their own (back to the `http://localhost/laravel/projectx/public/user/me` URL). Any idea in how I can do that?

My routes are as follows, but it does not work?

```
Route::get('/user/', array(
'as' => 'profile',
'uses' => 'ProfileController@user'
));

Route::get('/user/{username}', array(
'as' => 'profile-user',
'uses' => 'ProfileController@user'
));
```

And the code in the ProfileController controller:

```
public function user($username = null) {

    if($username != null) {
        $user = User::where('username', '=', $username);
        if($user->count()) {
            $user = $user->first();
            return View::make('profile.user')->with('name', $user->username);
        }
    }
    return View::make('profile')->with('name', Auth::user()->username);

}
```

Comment: Route::get('user/{username?}', ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use just one route:

```
Route::get('/user/{username?}', array(
    'as' => 'profile-user',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@user'
));
```

And I would go with something like this in your controller:

```
public function user($username = null) 
{
    $user = $username 
            ? User::where('username', '=', $username)->first() 
            : null;

    if ( ! $user && Auth::check())
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }

    return View::make('profile')->with('name', $user);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, still redirects to `localhost/user` when there is no user specified.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add a `?`. Edited.